# Why are my ' characters turned into \' when POSTed to my server?

Tags: html, forms, post, encoding

I'm not very strong in HTML, and each time I have some encoding problems.

Here, I have a form like :

```
<head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
[...]
<form method="post" action="thispage.php" >
    <input name="title" type="text" id="title" size=75 value="" />          
    <textarea name="description" rows="10" cols="80" id="description"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="GO"  />
</form>
```

When I write some quotes, like: `'`, it would arrive as `\'`
So `o'clock` will be `o\'clock`

Do you have an idea?

EDIT :

The strange thing is that quotes are not escaped in POST variables, according to firebug !

[image: check]

Comment: This sounds like a server-side problem, rather than a HTML problem

Comment: Unrelated to your problem — please upgrade from your legacy character encoding. We should have escaped ISO-8859 with the turn of the century. Move to [UTF-8](http://www.utf8everywhere.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be using a less then entirely up to date version of PHP and have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on.

Comment: If you check my edit, can you confirm your answer ? And if so, what line of the phpinfo() page can I check ?

Comment: Yes. Since magic quotes is a PHP feature, you won't see them when you ask the client what it is sending (because the client isn't sending them).

Comment: No idea if it is in `phpinfo()` or not. Use [`get_magic_quotes_gpc()` to tell](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php).

Comment: Ow ! I've got these f***ing magic quotes ! It's a mutualized server, they never will change this! Thanks anyway, guy.

Comment: Then every time you get input that magic quotes will touch, you need to test if magic quotes is on (so you aren't tripped up when they upgrade to a version of PHP that doesn't support them) and then `stripslashes` over the data … or move to a decent server.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and you should include your last comment in your answer.