# Backslashes added to ' on work server but not on local

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are my ' characters turned into \' when POSTed to my server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837148/why-are-my-characters-turned-into-when-posted-to-my-server)

Just put my site live. For some reasons backslashes are added ' signs even though I only do escape them before inserting to db. This only happens on the work server, not my local server. Where should I look? I don't think this is a script issue.

Comment: I understood nothing from this question. What code do you have? What is the problem? How does the output look like? How do you want it to look like? I usually don't downvote questions, but with over 75 questions here on SO, you should know how to ask questions!

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have [magic quotes turned off](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Check out: **[Disabling Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)**

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why it was on by default as I'm on 5.3.13 php...

Comment: @domino: You are welcome and those are removed from version `5.4.0.` :)